# looking for conceptual help on how to make a fragment shader warp images

Tags: android, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I have a need use a pixel (or vertex) shader to warp a texture such that the black line becomes the red line in the image below. Essentially, there is an arc with its midpoint in B and its endpoints at A,D and C,D. I then need some kind of smooth falloff coming out of there so that the image doesn't look sheered. A,B,C, and D are in my vertex list. I can add them as uniform variables to the shader as well if necessary. How would you approach the problem? I was originally thinking that I only needed to check in the critical rectangle, but I think now that the transform should apply to every pixel. Any ideas on the easiest way to do this would be appreciated; I'm just looking for general ideas. If there is a better forum for this question, please let me know. [image]

Comment: If it helps the discussion, suppose that I want to warp an image with a sine wave going across 10% of the height.